# ImportError: No module named 'firebase_admin'

Tags: python, ubuntu, сервер, firebase, putty

Закинул телеграм бота написанного на питоне в VPS сервер. Использую для запуска программу Putty.
 На сервере стоит ubuntu16.04.
Решил запустить его:

```
#python3.5 chinabiznesbot.py
```

На что получил ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "chinabiznesbot.py", line 4, in <module>
import firebase_admin
ImportError: No module named 'firebase_admin'
```

Как мне решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Знакомый подсказал:

```
pip install firebase-admin
pip install --user firebase-admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы посмотреть доступные модули - используйте команду:

```
help("modules")
```

Чтобы просмотреть где python ищет для подключения модули:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Может быть что каталог с модулем не добавлен в `PYTHONPATH`

Если необходимый модуль всё таки отсутствует установите его. Посмотрите особенности установки модулей, например, здесь: 
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/